# div positions while page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div left and right and on left part I set position fixed while scrolling and when scroll is about to finish I remove position and set it to bottom zero. Similar concept like flipkart does on their product detail page.

This is my code for that.
Javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10 ) {   
   $(".fixedSlider").addClass("DivAffix");
   $(".fixedSlider").removeClass("DivBottom");
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()  - 100) {

    $(".fixedSlider").removeClass("DivAffix");
    $(".fixedSlider").addClass("DivBottom");
  }  
} else {

}
});
```

css

```
.DivAffix{position: fixed;width: 480px;}
.DivBottom{position: absolute;bottom: 0}    
.fixedSlider { min-height: 516px;}
```

It's working fine but when I increase the resolution the left part not working properly. It jerks and set to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Actually with your code after scroll `> 10` it will add/remove class then after scroll higher than `window` which in the same time `> 10` your code will add/remove then remove/add classes on each scroll ..

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10  && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height()  - 100) {   
     $(".fixedSlider").addClass("DivAffix").removeClass("DivBottom");
  }
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()  - 100) {
    $(".fixedSlider").removeClass("DivAffix").addClass("DivBottom");
  }
});
```

**Here is the demo** *but I changed a little bit on css to notice the action*

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10  && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height()  - 100) {   
    $(".fixedSlider").addClass("DivAffix").removeClass("DivBottom");
  }
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()  - 100) {
    $(".fixedSlider").removeClass("DivAffix").addClass("DivBottom");
  }
});
```

```css
#content{
  height : 2000px;
}
.DivAffix{position: fixed;width: 100px ; bottom : 0;}
.DivBottom{position: relative;bottom: 0}    
.fixedSlider {min-height: 116px;background : red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">Content</div>
<div class="fixedSlider">fixedSlider</div>
```