# Hold element in place at specific offset to top then release after 1000px scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I'm trying to do something that I think has to do with parallax or sticky libraries but having a bunch of trouble.

I'd like to let the user scroll normally, and then when a particular div is a particular value (lets say 232px) from the top of the screen, I want to hold the element in place (ie give it position:fixed). This part is easy to get the offset:

```
$('element')product1[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

Then, let the user continue to scroll with the element in place so they can see the background continue to move with the scroll (I have a large height background with a nice linear-gradient).

Then after the user scrolled for about 1000px I want to release the element and let it continue to move up with the scroll. The same should happen when the user scrolls back up - it holds for a bit then releases.

I've tried a bunch of different things and combinations of libraries, pure css, JS, etc. Nothing works well. Everything has an issue. Would love to see a clean solution.

Things I've tried:
-JQuery sticky libraries (could not find one that does or is customizable to what I need)
-Vanilla JS tracking position (had jumping issues on release - element would fly far away on release, not continue from release position)
-CSS, specifically translateZ

The ideal setup is:

```
<div style="height: 230vh; background: linear-gradient(coolOne)">
   <div class="containerToStickTemporarily">
      <p class="textOnLeft">Hi</p>
      <img src="myImage.png"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I'd like to have multiple of these in a row.

Comment: Have you checked out Waypoints? http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574995/div-positions-while-page-scroll/44575061#

Comment: @mjw I mentioned I was able to accomplish this in vanilla but had other visual issues with releasing and keeping track of being below and above. If you can come up with solid logic that doesn't screw up the visuals on release (with or without this lib) please let me know!

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thank you but this would have similar troubles to what I did as well. I will try and create a gif of the behavior I want

Comment: Could you turn your "ideal setup" into a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to work with, perhaps by including some of the CSS you're applying and JavaScript you've already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that.. I guess

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     var top = $(window).scrollTop();

     $('element').css({ position: top > 230 && top < 1000 ? 'fixed' : 'relative' });
})
```